# Can not append system properties from profile config

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I have build configuration for maven failsafe plugin which includes `systemPropertyVariables`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Also I have a profile which can append few properties to same plugin via `pluginManagement`:

```
<profile>
  <id>test</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>test.host</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
              <TEST_HOST>test.host</TEST_HOST>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</profile>
```

But I can't read properties from this profile. It's working fine if I delete `systemPropertyVariables` in build plugin configuration section and keep in pluginManagement configuration of profile. It seems that I need to merge these properties when used together, so I tried to add `combine.children="append"` and `combine.self="append"` to `configuration` of plugin, but it didn't help.

**UPDATE:**
I've found the cause of this issue: I didn't mention that I have parent pom including from this one, and parent `pom.xml` has these lines:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration combine.children="append"> 
          <systemProperties>
            <!-- some properties that I don't use -->
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

And these parent pom failsafe configuration is breaking all configs in my `pom.xml` - if I remove parent pom reference, failsafe properties will be included correctly. I can't just remove parent pom reference and can't modify it (actually I can fork it and edit, but it's not an easy task), is it possible to override these properties, since I don't use them?

Attached minimal reproducible project: https://send.firefox.com/download/88dfb9f933c9567f/#71ij1jbuEuAYgdwIiZQZRg

Comment: Can you provide a downloadable example?

Comment: Have you tried doing such as `mvn help:effective-pom -Ptest` ?  A quick try here, with exactly the XML above, showed both `<buildDirectory>` and `<TEST_HOST>` under `<systemPropertyVariables>`

Comment: @MarinosAn @df778899 sorry for long reply, didn't have a time to check it deeper, I updated the question with more details about `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding an extra pom in between the *untouchable* (or `pariah`) parent and current `child`, I call this new middle pom `midboy` =)

So `midboy` has only the following difference from `pariah`;

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
</plugin>
```

And this pom becomes the the new parent pom of the `child`, while it uses the original `pariah` pom as its parent.

`child` ---[inherits]---> `midboy` ---[inherits]---> `pariah`

With `inherited:false` I essentially cut-off the failsafe plugin being passed into the `child` and breaking its profile-based configuration addition to its own local failsafe plugin & config. & this works perfectly!

No skipping of the test this time!

```
Running com.test.so51905256.PropITCase
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.031 s - in com.test.so51905256.PropITCase
```

p.s. don't forget to add some sort of `<activation>` for the `test` profile